# Inflating custom View in ListView according to position

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have a `ListView` where I would like to inflate a custom `View` at a certain position. It's actually the 11th item (position 10).

The `getCount()` method returns 11.

Here is the top part of the `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {              
        if (position < 10) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.standard, null);           
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "Inflated custom layout");
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "getView, position = "+position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);             
        convertView.setTag(holder);             
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ...
    Log.i(TAG, "getView() : position = " + position);
}
```

Here's what I see in the logcat:

```
getView, position = 0
getView, position = 1
getView, position = 2
```

The rest of the getView logs do NOT show; I would assume that this line would appear all the way up to `getView, position = 10`.

And this line: `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);` is never called, because `Inflated custom layout` doesn't show up in the logcat.

It's funny though, because the bottom logcat is called always (as I scroll down the `ListView`):

```
getView() : position = 0
getView() : position = 1
getView() : position = 2
getView() : position = 3
getView() : position = 4
getView() : position = 5
getView() : position = 6
getView() : position = 7
getView() : position = 8
getView() : position = 9
getView() : position = 10
```

**Why** is my custom layout not inflated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inflate the layout when the `getView()` methods `View convertView` is not null. The `View` which is returned from `getView()` will be reused. If you check the view is null and inflate it will inflate only when its first time returning the `View`.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {              
        if (position < 10) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.standard, null);           
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "getView, position = "+position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);             
        convertView.setTag(holder);             
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ...

    if(position > 10) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
         Log.i(TAG, "Inflated custom layout");
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "getView() : position = " + position);
}
```

Comment: But in this case every time when position goes above 10 custom view will be inflated right ? Suppose if the getView method call for 100 times with position as 11 then 100 instance of that view will be created..

Comment: yes that is the requirement. the listview will call Runtime.gc() every time the listitems are out of the visibleView.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate custom layout outside `convertView == null`. Since, convertView will usually return a previously recycled view and hence, your custom view never gets inflated.