# whatsApp like configuration layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to implement a configuration layout like the one in whatsApp.

The layout looks like a listview, but every row can have different layout and onclick event.

Using a listview doesn't seems to be the right choice, so I tried to mimic the layout with a vertical linearlayout and several textviews, but turned out the look and feel doesn't quite right.

Am I missing any default layout? Or any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

**Listview like layout**
[image]

**When the row is onclick**
[image]

Comment: my suggestion check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: exactly what I want, thanks Samara

Comment: It's called a PreferenceScreen, in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Inflating custom View in ListView according to position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098886/inflating-custom-view-in-listview-according-to-position)
as u can see, u can use layout inflator

```
if(position > 10) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
         Log.i(TAG, "Inflated custom layout");
 }
```

Also you can inflate different fragments with your menu block, and describe logic of clicking, checking, etc... in fragment's.